Identifying Stochastic Processes in Financial Data: Is There a Standard Approach?
In many theoretical models in mathematical finance, certain processes are assumed to follow specific stochastic dynamics. For example, order flow might be modeled using an Ornstein-Uhlenbeck (OU) process, or the evolution of a mid-price might follow a geometric Brownian motion.
Given a dataset (e.g., order flow, mid-price, alpha signal, etc.), what is the proper statistical procedure to infer whether the underlying process belongs to a particular family of stochastic processes (such as OU or geometric Brownian motion)? Once the process family is identified, how can I estimate the parameters or determine the specific member of that family that best fits the data?
Also, are there well-known families of stochastic processes commonly used in finance for modeling such dynamics? How would I handle more complex cases, like models where processes involve jumps or other components driven by secondary distributions?
I would appreciate any guidance on the procedure or suggestions for known process families, if they exist.
Thanks in advance for your help!

In short: there is no such standard. The model choice is more of an art than an exact science and is driven also by the type of derivative one is pricing. For example: barrier options depend a lot on the volatility smile. So a model is required that can capture this (local vol, stochastic vol or both). For a plain vanilla option Black-Scholes is sufficient.

@-Kurt G  Thanks!
So for example in the case of knowing that the order flow follows the following process:
d(mu)t = -\kappa mu_t + \eta{1+N_t} dN_t
when \eta_i ~ F for each i.
the case is that F is unknown, also N_t comes from Poison so its not deterministic.
how would you address this kind of modeling?
Also, can you please address some known families of processes for modeling (e.g. OU)?

I am glad that I am retired and don't have to do that :) Seems you are not pricing something but instead want to model a time series "properly". There are other experts but I would recommend a more specific question. You started with OU and GBM and now we are talking about order flow and Poisson. Way too broad.

I have a theoretical solution for a control problem given assumptions, among those that the positive and negative order flows are in the form I have mentioned in the last comment. I want to check if the model holds on real data, therefore to derive the specific OU process that they follow. in order to do that I have to estimate F... how to do it?
But, you are right the original phrase is a combined 2 questions.. the second one is how in advance I know to model that as OU process... what processes families I need to be aware of?

I cannot even read that d(mu)_t formula. This calls for a proper post using mathJax. The Poisson process is a nice subject. The OU-Process that I am familiar with has nothing to do with Poisson.

@Kurt G
I have published it under the title "Question: Estimating Parameters for a Jump Ornstein-Uhlenbeck Process from Positive and Negative Order Flow Time Series
". I would be glad if you could help!

Hi: Stefano Iacus has written a book that covers his Yuima package which is a package in R. I don't know if his book covers what you want ( classes of processes and how to identify them ? ) but it's probably worth it to check it out.
